# Understading Mocking -Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-django

I am Writing a web application using `Django`, where users can upload images to `aws s3`. i  am newbie to testing. when i googled, i found that when writing `tests`, we should avoid using external resources such us `file system storage, file` which causes more time delay in tests as well.so to overcome that we have to use `mock`, but i am unclear that if i use mock we can't make sure file gets uploaded to `s3` or not right.how `mocking` helps in that case?

Comment: Hint (not answer): unit testing, integration testing and system testing are 3 different testing phases. Mocking as for unit testing.

Comment: You would mock HTTP responses from s3 (or the appropriate protocol if they don't use HTTP). Pure unit tests shouldn't be used to talk to external systems.

Comment: @phd thanks, so mocking will used only in unittest, which won't raise any exception when external resources failure. if i want to test something which access other resources such us file upload process it comes under `integration` test right?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Thanks, i am using [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) to handle `file upload`, i hope it handles file upload during `pre_save` signal, so i can't mock http response right?, i found this article [this](https://joeray.me/mocking-files-and-file-storage-for-testing-django-models.html) which `mocks` file system only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468127/mock-test-case-to-upload-file-to-s3